# Error: Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want update several row from database table with `foreach` but give following error:

This is my php code:

```
$id_units       = $this->input->post('id_units');
$name_un       = $this->input->post('name_units');      
$price_un        = $this->input->post('price_units');
$description_un = $this->input->post('explanation_units');
$ex_un       = $this->input->post('addition_units');
$service_un        = $this->input->post('checkbox_units');
$data2 = array();
foreach ($name_un as $idx => $name) {
    $data2 = array(
        'relation' => $id_residence,
        'name_un' => $name_un[$idx],
        'price_un' => $price_un[$idx],
        'description_un' => $description_un[$idx],
        'ex_un' => $ex_un[$idx],
        'service_un' => json_encode($service_un[$idx]), // This Is Line Number: 212
    );
$this->db->update('hotel_units', $data2, array('id' => $id_units[$idx]));
};
```

Above code have this error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>  Error Number: 1054
>  Unknown column
>   'Array' in 'where clause'
>  UPDATE `hotel_units` SET `0` = Array
>   WHERE `id` = Array
>  Filename:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php
>  Line Number: 330

**Update:**

I have new error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message:
>   Undefined offset: 1
>  Filename: residence.php
>  Line Number:
>   212
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined offset: 2
>  Filename: residence.php
>  Line
>   Number: 212
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity:
>   Notice
>  Message: Undefined offset: 3
>  Filename:
>   residence.php
>  Line Number: 212

`'service_un' =>...` are checkbox. See Line Number: 212 in above php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$id_units` is an array of values.

You could try with this code, but it assumes that, like the rest of your input fields, id is also an array and has the same index of the others. You didn't provide your html form so I'm just guessing....Anyway, the last param of $this->db->where() needs to be a single value, even if you write it as an array (but of one element).

```
$id_units       = $this->input->post('id_units');
$name_un       = $this->input->post('name_units');      
$price_un        = $this->input->post('price_units');
$description_un = $this->input->post('explanation_units');
$ex_un       = $this->input->post('addition_units');
$service_un        = $this->input->post('checkbox_units');
$data2 = array();
foreach ($name_un as $idx => $name) {
    $data2 = array(
        'relation' => $id_residence,  // Or is it $id_residence[$idx] ?
        'name_un' => $name_un[$idx],
        'price_un' => $price_un[$idx],
        'description_un' => $description_un[$idx],
        'ex_un' => $ex_un[$idx],
        'service_un' => json_encode($service_un[$idx]),
    );
   $this->db->update('hotel_units', $data2, array('id' => $id_units[$idx]));
};
```

Comment: Yeah it is array, but i have now this error: `Unknown column '0' in 'field list', 
UPDATE 'hotel_units' SET '0' = Array WHERE 'id' = '32'`

Comment: @Alicia Cibrian got it, I corrected my answer: should be `$data2`, not `$data2[]`, I didn't see it before

Comment: Could you post your html form? Otherwise it would be just a game of guessing by my part...You'll get more help even from other people if you could post the structure of your form